# HTML Overflow Child and Parent DIV

Tags: html, css

How to avoid content from a child div overflowing the parent container? This is probably one of the most frequent question ever asked and the most frequent and a working solution is to use `max-height:100%`, which ofcourse works.

The problem is when I cannot use `100%`, for example, in the **given jsfiddle**, I have an header which takes some `x pixel` height. I can of course arbitrarily decrease the percentage but it is unstable when the window is resized.

[JSFiddle - FUpsA](http://jsfiddle.net/FUpsA/)

**Edit:**
I like to mention that the Header should not be a part of the scrolling content, hence using `overflow:auto` on the parent div is not an option.

Comment: use css property `overflow: hidden`. While it doesn't stop overflow as such, it makes the overflowing content invisible.

Comment: You mean something like that http://jsfiddle.net/FUpsA/2/ ?

Comment: Another way would be to set `overflow:auto;` just on the parent div and nothing on the others.  But this would imply, that the header is also part of the scrollable content.

Comment: If you know the height of the div, then you can enter the height manually. If the height may vary depends upon the screen height. Then you should go with javascript solution.

Comment: @Alek, exactly like that, however, if I use `max-height:75%` in the child div and the window resizes the child div again overflows because the header is of static height, but I do not know the height and I am trying to avoid using javascript as far as possible.

Comment: @Zhonk, exactly, the header becomes a part of the scrolling content :(

Comment: @sriraman, very true and that is the solution I've implemented now (javascript) but I wish to avoid it as far as possible.

Comment: @Bartdude, it makes the content invisible hence does not help much.

Comment: Then I don't understand your issue. If you have a fixed height parent like in your jsfiddle and your children overflows, either you show it (which is generally ugly), either you hide it. If you want your parent to grow with its child, just don't fix its height...

Comment: @Bartdude, I want the child to be a scrollable content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues came up with a very interesting solution and I was simply amazed! The solution is compatible with IE 5.5+ and its purely CSS.

He used the property of containers with `postion:relative` which modifies the scope of their child elements with `position:absolute`. more information about that at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

This is a sample structure of the solution, refer the fiddle for more details

```
<div id='parent' style='position:relative'>
   <div id='header' style='height:75px'>
      <!-- Header -->
   </div>
   <div id='child' style='position:absolute; top:75px;bottom:0px; overflow:auto'>
      <!-- Content-->
   </div>
</div>
```

Note that the height is set only for the static content and not for the dynamic content

[JSFiddle - FUpsA - Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/FUpsA/12/)

Answer (score 2):

According your reply on my comment i suggest to use `css` `calc`:

**html**

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;border:2px solid #000;">
    <div>
        <h2>Some Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="mainTextCont" style="overflow:auto;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sem ipsum, sagittis non leo vel, imperdiet molestie massa. Cras convallis nisl id quam tristique, sit amet venenatis quam tristique. Donec feugiat interdum justo, eu volutpat leo lacinia hendrerit. Donec consequat risus ac leo molestie venenatis. Nulla eleifend lobortis tincidunt. Duis lobortis, ligula ac bibendum tempor, eros neque dignissim leo, nec aliquet turpis turpis eget lectus. Maecenas convallis velit ac nunc euismod, vel cursus orci tincidunt. Aenean convallis fermentum porttitor. Phasellus nunc mauris, tincidunt in aliquet quis, tempor in lectus. Vestibulum faucibus velit ultrices, fringilla nunc sed, aliquet tellus. Vivamus id turpis sed nibh sagittis dictum. Morbi ut eros consectetur, fermentum mauris eget, porttitor metus. Praesent ut magna rutrum, eleifend nulla in, vehicula libero.

Integer accumsan, tellus sit amet tincidunt semper, sem purus convallis mauris, a accumsan ante lacus vel leo. Suspendisse suscipit sollicitudin velit ut sodales. Aenean id nisl tellus. Morbi sagittis tincidunt elementum. Fusce consectetur consectetur metus ut tempor. Fusce fermentum dui tortor, sit amet fringilla ligula venenatis id. Nulla facilisi. Fusce eu felis justo. Sed vel ultrices massa. In tincidunt auctor posuere. Morbi tristique orci dolor, sit amet aliquet dui tincidunt sit amet. Sed posuere metus quis est tincidunt, quis euismod arcu vestibulum. Sed vestibulum in lacus vel hendrerit.

Etiam ultrices, ante in tempus dictum, nisl dui ultrices felis, et pellentesque arcu nisi sed justo. In sollicitudin, nibh et malesuada elementum, augue metus euismod quam, ut sollicitudin nulla turpis vel mauris. Phasellus ut dapibus enim. Donec tempus orci nec est aliquam, non scelerisque nibh pharetra. Cras scelerisque elementum libero, a faucibus turpis congue consectetur. Aliquam non est non elit luctus tincidunt sed sed orci. Suspendisse mollis ante arcu. Maecenas molestie erat mauris, sed egestas sapien malesuada nec. Quisque et ante id nunc scelerisque egestas.

Etiam vitae leo vitae turpis commodo semper vel ut justo. Curabitur aliquet iaculis lacus, vel pellentesque eros cursus in. Donec eget dui viverra, convallis libero vel, blandit dolor. Sed vulputate diam quis lacus tincidunt ullamcorper. Proin viverra ligula sem. Nulla tempus felis enim, a scelerisque dui rhoncus lacinia. Ut iaculis auctor faucibus. Phasellus purus lectus, tempor vel tellus sit amet, varius consequat lorem. Donec eget consectetur nunc. Vestibulum vulputate euismod dictum.

Nullam nec nisi non nunc feugiat gravida. Sed tincidunt mi eleifend, posuere lacus commodo, adipiscing arcu. Proin pharetra augue vitae elit mollis, eu porta turpis pellentesque. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat id ante dapibus tincidunt. Quisque scelerisque imperdiet commodo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc velit sapien, tincidunt non consectetur in, pellentesque nec justo.
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#mainTextCont{
    height: calc(100% - 75px);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUpsA/4/)

Comment: I accept that is a very good solution, I definitely have to agree to that but support for calc is relatively low, only IE 9+ supports it.

Comment: Provide the correct fiddle. Thx for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:

add `overflow:hidden;` in parent `div` sorry I did not notice that you don't want to change height.. now its as per your requirement.

Like this:

```
<div style="width:300px;overflow:hidden; height:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;border:2px solid #000;">
    <div>
        <h2>Some Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto; max-height:100%">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sem ipsum, sagittis non leo vel, imperdiet molestie massa. Cras convallis nisl id quam tristique, sit amet venenatis quam tristique.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sem ipsum, sagittis non leo vel, imperdiet molestie massa. Cras convallis nisl id quam tristique, sit amet venenatis quam tristique.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sem ipsum, sagittis non leo vel, imperdiet molestie massa. Cras convallis nisl id quam tristique, sit amet venenatis quam tristique.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sem ipsum, sagittis non leo vel, imperdiet molestie massa. Cras convallis nisl id quam tristique, sit amet venenatis quam tristique.
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He mentioned in the question that he don't want solution like this. Since it will be unstable.

Comment: @Gagan, interesting solution, there is a tiny glitch in your solution, because the parent div has a overflow hidden, a small part of the child container is hidden, try adding more content to your solution and scroll down, you will find some text missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `overflow:hidden;` to your **parent div** and for **child div** set height less than parent div ie `height:210px`

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;border:2px solid #000; overflow:hidden;">
    <div>
        <h2>Some Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:210px">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sem ipsum, sagittis non leo vel, imperdiet molestie massa. Cras convallis nisl id quam tristique, sit amet venenatis quam tristique. Donec feugiat interdum justo, eu volutpat leo lacinia hendrerit. Donec consequat risus ac leo molestie venenatis. Nulla eleifend lobortis tincidunt. Duis lobortis, ligula ac bibendum tempor, eros neque dignissim leo, nec aliquet turpis turpis eget lectus. Maecenas convallis velit ac nunc euismod, vel cursus orci tincidunt. Aenean convallis fermentum porttitor. Phasellus nunc mauris, tincidunt in aliquet quis, tempor in lectus. Vestibulum faucibus velit ultrices, fringilla nunc sed, aliquet tellus. Vivamus id turpis sed nibh sagittis dictum. Morbi ut eros consectetur, fermentum mauris eget, porttitor metus. Praesent ut magna rutrum, eleifend nulla in, vehicula libero.

Integer accumsan, tellus sit amet tincidunt semper, sem purus convallis mauris, a accumsan ante lacus vel leo. Suspendisse suscipit sollicitudin velit ut sodales. Aenean id nisl tellus. Morbi sagittis tincidunt elementum. Fusce consectetur consectetur metus ut tempor. Fusce fermentum dui tortor, sit amet fringilla ligula venenatis id. Nulla facilisi. Fusce eu felis justo. Sed vel ultrices massa. In tincidunt auctor posuere. Morbi tristique orci dolor, sit amet aliquet dui tincidunt sit amet. Sed posuere metus quis est tincidunt, quis euismod arcu vestibulum. Sed vestibulum in lacus vel hendrerit.

Etiam ultrices, ante in tempus dictum, nisl dui ultrices felis, et pellentesque arcu nisi sed justo. In sollicitudin, nibh et malesuada elementum, augue metus euismod quam, ut sollicitudin nulla turpis vel mauris. Phasellus ut dapibus enim. Donec tempus orci nec est aliquam, non scelerisque nibh pharetra. Cras scelerisque elementum libero, a faucibus turpis congue consectetur. Aliquam non est non elit luctus tincidunt sed sed orci. Suspendisse mollis ante arcu. Maecenas molestie erat mauris, sed egestas sapien malesuada nec. Quisque et ante id nunc scelerisque egestas.

Etiam vitae leo vitae turpis commodo semper vel ut justo. Curabitur aliquet iaculis lacus, vel pellentesque eros cursus in. Donec eget dui viverra, convallis libero vel, blandit dolor. Sed vulputate diam quis lacus tincidunt ullamcorper. Proin viverra ligula sem. Nulla tempus felis enim, a scelerisque dui rhoncus lacinia. Ut iaculis auctor faucibus. Phasellus purus lectus, tempor vel tellus sit amet, varius consequat lorem. Donec eget consectetur nunc. Vestibulum vulputate euismod dictum.

Nullam nec nisi non nunc feugiat gravida. Sed tincidunt mi eleifend, posuere lacus commodo, adipiscing arcu. Proin pharetra augue vitae elit mollis, eu porta turpis pellentesque. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat id ante dapibus tincidunt. Quisque scelerisque imperdiet commodo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc velit sapien, tincidunt non consectetur in, pellentesque nec justo.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want to set custom height to the child div, it becomes unstable when the window is resized or used across other displays.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow is for the parent and describes how to wrap the child contents.

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;border:2px solid #000;overflow:auto;">
    <div>
        <h2>Some Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sem ipsum...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is sheer genius and it works fine but sorry, I forgot to mention that **I require the header to be on top**, though it is clear from the fiddle I have put up, I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FUpsA/13/ 
I would suggest to work out the layout and its dimensions in pixels or percentages prior to converting them into the Ui , this would save time and give you an idea. In your case , you can wrap the scrolling div with a fixed size in pixels and then applying 100% to the inner DIV.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the header takes up space. When you combine the headers height with 100% of the parent (percentages are based on the parent element) it is going to be over 100% of course.

What you should do is make the headers height one percentage and the text part other percentage.

For example:

```
    <div style="width:300px; height:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;border:2px solid #000;">

    <div style="height: 20%;">
        <h2>Some Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto; max-height:70%">
        ...
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: This solution does not solve my purpose because I cannot be sure of the window size. Hence reducing the header size might cause it to be hidden

Comment: The percentage ain't from the window height, it's from the parent element. So 20% in first div is always 20% * 300px. Unless you're going to also resize the outer div, it's going to be always the right size.